# Java SimpleDateFormat parsed datetime is different with Calendar datetime

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I run follow code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm zzz");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

and I got :

```
Mon Jan 25 18:32:52 CST 2016
2016-01-25 06:32 CST
```

I am in China . why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `SimpleDateFormat`, the `hh` specifier formats the date for a 12 hour clock (usually used with `am/pm` notation). If you need a 24 hour clock, use `HH` or `kk`:

```
...
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm zzz");
...
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html:

> **H** Hour in day (0-23)
>
> **k** Hour in day (1-24)
>
> **h** Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Comment: Thank you very much , I am too careless.